# How To Change DNS Server?

Tags: networking, arch-linux, systemd, dns, networkmanager

I tether Internet to my PC from my phone via USB cable, so I get this in my `/etc/resolv.conf`:

```
# Generated by NetworkManager
nameserver 192.168.114.150
```

I guess that `192.168.114.150` just points to my phone. If NM overrides this file, how can I change it to my preferred DNS server?

Comment: Do name resolution works on your computer? Your internet provider will probably give you the nameserver via DHCP (when you get also the IP of the "internet side"). See here if you real question is about changing nameserver in NM: https://askubuntu.com/questions/246077/how-to-setup-a-static-ip-for-network-manager-in-virtual-box-on-ubuntu-server

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi >Do name resolution works on your computer? I don't know what it is. >Your internet provider will probably give you the nameserver via DHCP. Couldn't it be bypassed?

Comment: "name resolution": if you try to access e.g. google.com, do it gives you something or it just tell you he cannot find his address? -- for the second part: the link on my comment is about setting static name servers

Comment: @GiacomoCatenazzi this name server provided by NM works. I just want to change it to something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can of course tell NetworkManager not to write /etc/resolv.conf and do it yourself.

However, usually the DNS server depends on the network to which you are connecting, and isn't that static. Which is why in NetworkManager you would configure the DNS settings as part of the connection profile (which are the settings for a network).

For example, `nmcli connection show` lists all your profile. Check the details of one with `nmcli connection show "$PROFILE"`. See `man nm-settings` for the meaning of the fields. To set a static DNS server configure

```
  nmcli connection modify "$PROFILE" ipv4.dns 8.8.8.8 ipv4.ignore-auto-dns yes
```

Afterwards re-activate the profile with `nmcli connection up "$PROFILE"`.

Comment: `$PROFILE` variable is unset for me.

Comment: @MonsieurPierreDunn that variable is ment as a placeholder for a profile that you pick from `nmcli connection show`, e.g. `Wired` for LAN or a wifi SSID.

Comment: I found a script to do that for all connections: https://askubuntu.com/a/1384512/25300

Comment: And in case I would like to revert this back, I do `nmcli connection modify <profile> ipv4.ignore-auto-dns no`?

Answer (score 2):

The following method is [from the RedHat documentation](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_enterprise_linux/8/html/configuring_and_managing_networking/manually-configuring-the-etc-resolv-conf-file_configuring-and-managing-networking), but also works for me on Debian. It probably works the same or similarly for Arch Linux using systemd and NetworkManager.

> As the root user, create the /etc/NetworkManager/conf.d/90-dns-none.conf file with the following content by using a text editor:
>
> ```
> [main]
> dns=none
> ```
>
> Reload the NetworkManager service:
>
> ```
> # systemctl reload NetworkManager
> ```
>
> > Note
> >
> > After you reload the service, NetworkManager no longer updates the /etc/resolv.conf file. However, the last contents of the file are preserved.
>
> Optionally, remove the Generated by NetworkManager comment from /etc/resolv.conf to avoid confusion.

You can now edit the `/etc/resolv.conf` and it won't be overwritten by NetworkManager.

Edit: somebody suggested an edit, but I quoted directly from a documentation page, so it would not make sense to edit that quote. I leave their comment here instead.

> Without `rc-manager=unamanaged`, NM will rewrite the resolv.conf to a blank file, following your command blindly (dns=none; no dns).

Comment: Yes, it doesn't overwrite my `resolv.conf` anymore, but will the server that I put in there be actually used? How can I know it for sure? Could I add more servers in there?

Comment: I've reloaded NM, edited `resolv.conf` and run `nmcli --fields ip4.dns,ip6.dns dev show`. It shows me this: `IP4.DNS[1]: 192.168.114.150`.

Comment: You can verify for example with `dig` or `nslookup` that the server is used. And you can add multiple servers to the resolv.conf, one `nameserver <ip>` per line.

Comment: I see now that I also get my router's DNS from `nmcli`. I'm not entirely sure if that is still used by NetworkManager or just an info.

Comment: The standard lookup utilities use /etc/resolv.conf.  Individual programs, like dig or your browser, may still use other DNS depending on how they work.

Comment: @DarioSeidl those are showing me the server I've chosen, but I'm confused with the output of that `nmcli` command.

Comment: I'm not really sure about that either, but I believe most programs respect the DNS of resolv.conf and NetworkManager just shows which DNS the connection provides.